# How to make a Google user act as "Bot only on Server End"?

Tags: javascript, api, google-workspace

I am trying to make a google service for my school that basically goes like this:

Teacher adds a user ( bot@schoolname.com ) to their google classroom. 
The user scans through the calendar and works it magic ( copying it to other relevant calendars etc )

The problem is that I cant really seem to work out how to act as a user only on server side. Ive managed to do this with a client side consent-screen, but I cant figure out how to auth a regular user only server side?

The account is a school-account on G-suite, but I have the privileges.

Im using the Google-APIs library in Node.js and have tried all the examples given without luck.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I believe you will need App consent to propogate to other calendars, however you could use a shared calendar in g-suite. : https://support.google.com/a/answer/1626902?hl=en
Either way, we definitely need more informaiton on what you have tried.